# How to select a wifi ap depending of the user login

Tags: wireless

I have kids at home, I need to find a way to start the wifi connexion based on who is login in:

- kids => use access point ssid: CHILD
- adult => use access point ssid: ADULT

Lubuntu 12.04 LTS

Regards and thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I finally find by my self:

1- log as root:

```
sudo su -
```

2- create for each user the autostart directory into their homedir

```
mkdir -p /home/USERNAME/.config/autostart
```

3- copy the following code into a network.desktop file in the autostart dir for each users of your system

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=demarrage
Comment=Manage your network connections
Exec=/usr/local/bin/dhclient-util.sh
Type=Application
NoDisplay=true
```

4- copy the following code into /etc/local/bin/dhclient-util.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

##################################################################
# dhclient-util.sh
# script shell pour changer le fichier /etc/dhcpd/dhclient.conf
# pour y ajouter selon l util le dns de opendns
#
# entree: neant
#
# sortie: 0
#
# auteur: yves guerin (C) 2012 yvesguerin@yahoo.ca
#
# version:
#       0.0.1 : yguerin - 2012-12-12 : initiale
#################################################################

# prog
CP=`which cp`
GREP=`which grep`
NMCLI=`which nmcli`
SLEEP=`which sleep`
SUDO=`which sudo`

# var
DELAI="2"
TYPEUTIL="enfant"

# verif dans quelle liste se trouve  l`utilisateur 

RET=`${GREP} -w ${USER} /etc/dhcp/enfant.list`

# verif si vide
if [ ${#RET} -eq 0 ] ; then
        # vide, verif dans l`autre liste
        RET=`${GREP} -w ${USER} /etc/dhcp/parent.list`

        # verif si non vide
        if [ ${#RET} -gt 0 ] ; then
                # trouve
                TYPEUTIL="parent"
        fi
fi


# arrete  toute les connexions reseau
${NMCLI} nm enable false

case ${TYPEUTIL} in
        "parent" )
                # copie dhclient.conf pour adulte
                ${SUDO} ${CP} -f /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf.defaut /etc/dhcp/dhcli$
        ;;
        * )
                # sinon pour les autres dhclient.conf enfant opendns
                ${SUDO} ${CP} -f /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf.enfant /etc/dhcp/dhcli$
        ;;
esac

# attente
# attente
${SLEEP} ${DELAI}

# redemarre le reseau
${NMCLI} nm enable true

exit 0
```

5- make it executable

```
chmod gu+x /etc/local/bin/dhclient-util.sh
```

6- create the list of your user and write the username

```
touch /etc/dhcp/parent.list
echo joe >> /etc/dhcp/parent.list
touch /etc/dhcp/enfant.list
echo sophie >> /etc/dhcp/enfant.list
```

7- for every list create a dhclient.conf file with the options you want (see the dhclient-util.sh)

```
enfant.list => /etc/dhcp/dhclient.enfant.conf
parent.list => /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf.defaut
```

8- for the opendns domain name servers ip I added the following line into the /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf.enfant

```
supersede domain-name-servers 208.67.222.222, 208.67.220.220;
```

9- remove from the same file the "domain-name-servers" word from the "request"

That it :)

Usefull on laptop.

l2f

Comment: Excellent, +1 for both the question and answer.